# User Interface Automation Testing using White Framework

Tags: testing, user-interface, automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to automate a UI written in WPF. I have a list box consisting of a button as a list item..How can i get the instance for that particular button using White Framework? Even if i try to get an instance of the list box; it shows an error saying that unable to get the type i.e. list box

Comment: What have you got so far?  Can you post your code?

Comment: I was able to solve that problem on my own..I though have some other problem i am stuck with...Check out the link in the next comment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682035/unable-to-click-a-button-even-though-i-am-able-to-retrieve-it-using-the-name